Need help with texturing from ripped models
So recently, I managed to extract a model from a game that I play and after putting it into a blender and figuring out basic texturing with applying textures, I came across this weird issue where I can’t get the textures to work how they should. First image that’s attached as how it looks on blender and the second one is how it should look.



Maybe try adding Texture Coordinate node before your image ? Beside of that, I don't think anyone can find the issue without access to your blend file. You can pack your texture and hope it's small enough for blend-exchange.com

I have a thing called Parsec. and as for that node. how do I use it?

So, your mesh has a UV map, connect it to the textures (from "texture coordinate" node)

What do I connect from Texture coordinate node and to where?

Okay. I know I connect the UV node to somewhere but I don't know where or what to connect it to.

Would you consider yourself to be a beginner?

@JaketheOctoling I encourage you to watch or read some tutorials on that. It is what you could call basic things, you'll hardly learn anything by asking these questions to us here (too much things to explain). You need someone to explain the gist of it, e.g. tutorials. For your question, the Texture Coordinate > UV should be plugged into the Image Texture. See TheLabCat's answer for more information. If you have any specific question that doesn't find its answer on the web or here, feel free to open other question(s). Precise/specific questions are the best here.

Yes, I’m a beginner to ripping models from games. As to the program, I know some things about it but not much so definitely a beginner

This is a texture coordinates issue, at least on the surface level of the problem. The wrong texture may be in use in the material, resulting in this stretching, as the UV map wouldn’t be meant to apply to its aspect ratio. If you are sure the correct texture is in use, check the UV maps panel in the Properties editor and see if the mesh has more than one UV map. If so, you may be using the wrong one. You can pick a different one with a UV map node in the shader wired to the Texture node’s vector input. If it does not, the rip may have damaged or lost the UV map.
Related: What UV maps are and do.
